# Increasing Mathematica FunctionInterpolation Accuracy/Domain

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

My current problem is trying to use FunctionInterpolation[] on complicated functions, the easiest to see this is probably when you compare the difference between:

```
FunctionInterpolation[Sin[t], {t, 0, 30}]
Plot[%[t], {t, 0, 30}]
```

and

```
FunctionInterpolation[Sin[t], {t, 0, 1000}]
Plot[%[t], {t, 0, 30}]
```

By increasing the domain of the function the interpolation becomes very inaccurate, I'm looking for a way to create a FunctionInterpolation[] that has an arbitrarily high accuracy for an arbitrarily long domain. It appears to be possible for short domains but I have been unable so far to find a solution for both.

If this is not possible, why not? is there something special about the form of InterpolationFunction that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Do you know your function is periodic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to include derivatives as well :

```
FunctionInterpolation[{Sin[t], Cos[t], -Sin[t], -Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}]
Plot[%[t], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Ah, Thank you that was very useful... In trying to find information on the syntax you showed (which isn't on the functionintorpolation documentation) I found a possibly equivalent method that does appear to allow arbitrary precision:

    FunctionInterpolation[{Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 30]

Comment: @user1694253 Yes it is, please look at the example under the Scope section.

Comment: For future reference this documentation appears to be mostly valid for functioniterpolate too.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html

Comment: ah, yes you are right. Now I feel slightly stupid/blind. Thanks again though.

Comment: @user1694253 Hey no problem, it happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can apparently increase the underlying sampling frequency by using an undocumented syntax for the function range:

```
FunctionInterpolation[Sin[t], {t, 0, 1000, 20}]

Plot[%[t], {t, 0, 30}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It's interesting that even in the current version of Mathematica 10.3.0.0, the syntax highlighter colors this "red", for an error, even though it works.

Comment: @JessRiedel It is worth to send them a suggestion/report about this issue: the more reports, the higher probability it'll be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 2):

Try the undocumented option `InterpolationOrder->n` with a large `n` like, say `50`:

```
With[{func = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[t], {t, 0, 1000}]}, 
  Plot[func[x], {x, 150, 160}]
]
```

[image]

```
With[{func = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[t], {t, 0, 1000}, InterpolationOrder -> 50]}, 
  Plot[func[x], {x, 150, 160}]
]
```

[image]

You can also try the undocumented `InterpolationPoints`:

```
With[{func = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[t], {t, 0, 1000}, InterpolationPoints -> 50]}, 
  Plot[func[x], {x, 150, 160}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Further reading about undocumented `FunctionInterpolation` options: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85103/280

Comment: thanks, note `InterpolationPoints` evidently behaves as the `PlotPoints` option to `Plot`, more points are generated as needed.  I'd caution the `InterpolationOrder` approach might not work so well if the function was not so smooth.

Comment: Agreed. Large values of `InterpolationOrder` are just extended Taylor series, so they probably only make sense for function that are analytic (or nearly so).